# Crud operation using express and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, express

How can I do a crud operation using express.js and Postgresql as I'm new to express js and Postgresql .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your server with `express`
2. Connect your Postgres DB to `express` using npm `node-postgres`
3. Create your Rest API with `expresss`
4. Connect your APIs to `DB`

Comment: Do not use node-postgres. Instead use e.g. [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg).